# Preview the sequence in Premiere

Tags: premiere

I have two workstations with the same configuration, with the same version of Premiere and the same project file.  Why on the first workstation, can I preview the sequence without needing to render while on the other workstation to be able to preview the sequence, I need to render?

Answer (score 0):

Because the workstations most likely don't have the same specs? From what I understand I assume that the other workspace runs slowly in preview or required you to pre-render the sequence in order to play it smoothly. In that case, check your ram, cpu and gpu and upgrade it accordingly. If that is not the problem at hand, please clarify what it is.

Comment: the two workstations are identical in every way

Comment: please specify, what do you mean when you say you "need to render". Can you see anything in the preview? Is it simply not playing smoothly or not at all? What are your premiere settings? Are you using CUDA?

Comment: We focus our attention on the colored rendering bars in the time ruler of a sequence.  On the first workstation the color is yellow.  If I make changes to the sequence, I can instantly preview the changes.  On the other workstation, after making changes to the sequence, the color of the bar changes to red and in order to have the preview, the software starts the rendering process.  After rendering, the bar turns green.

Comment: Now we're getting somewhere. Is the sequence you opened the exact same? Are there any differences in the footage, its scaling, proxy or applied effects? Those would be my first guesses...

Comment: Yes, I did a test, opening the same project and applying the same effects

Comment: @florian-claaßenthere is one thing that naively I had not yet verified. the video card drivers are not the same on the two workstations. on the first, I had downloaded updated drivers while on the second I had left the initial drivers. There is only one problem. I installed the updated drivers also on the second workstation, but the color of the bar is still red.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked that both workstations are running the same background processes and the same versions of OS and all software? My guess would be one of them doing something intensive in the background or a version mismatch somewhere.